# How to make adjustbox work correctly with wrapfigure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure, adjustbox

I have an adjustbox environment which gives colored background to content. 
It doesn't play nicely with wrapfigure. It overlaps with the content. Below is the mew.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newenvironment{bluebox}{%
    \noindent
    \adjustbox{innerenv={varwidth}[c]{1.1\linewidth},margin=\fboxsep+.25cm \fboxsep+.2cm,bgcolor=blue!10,frame,center}\bgroup
}{%

    \egroup
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3-5]
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{3.00in}
\begin{bluebox}
\lipsum[4]
\end{bluebox}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows: [image: wrapfigure_and_adjustbox].
The adjustbox overlaps with the rest of the content if used with wrapfigure. 
How can I fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use proper width for `varwidth`:

```
\adjustbox{innerenv={varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-0.45cm\relax},
    margin=\fboxsep+.25cm \fboxsep+.2cm,bgcolor=blue!10,frame,center}
```

I have subtracted the `margin` of `adjustbox` (\fboxsep+.25cm \fboxsep+.2cm,) from `\linewidth`. If you use `1.1\linewidth` contents will be wider and hence the undesired effect.

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newenvironment{bluebox}{%
    \noindent
    \adjustbox{innerenv={varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-0.45cm\relax},
    margin=\fboxsep+.25cm \fboxsep+.2cm,bgcolor=blue!10,frame,center}\bgroup
}{%
    \egroup
}

\begin{document}
\kant[3-5]
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{3.00in}
\begin{bluebox}
\kant[1]
\end{bluebox}
\end{wrapfigure}
\kant[3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for usage of the `kantlipsum` package.